# firebase mobile otp authentication issue after deploying?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My react website was initially sending otp  in localhost environment for phone authentication using firebase but after deploying in netlify it is not sending otp. but  its still working in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your link web after deploy to your firebase project. It's work for me.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YOHp.png